# get the compiler to read a string as a variable

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am trying to play a random audio clip in a game I am making in Phaser 3. I wish to play any of the following when a certain event happens:

```
audioBanshee0 = this.sound.add('audioBanshee0',{volume: 0.5});     
audioBanshee1 = this.sound.add('audioBanshee1',{volume: 0.5});     
audioBanshee2 = this.sound.add('audioBanshee2',{volume: 0.5});     
audioBanshee3 = this.sound.add('audioBanshee3',{volume: 0.5});    
audioBanshee4 = this.sound.add('audioBanshee4',{volume: 0.5});
```

I have tried the following:

```
var ref = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(5));
const audioBansheeScreech = "audioBanshee" + ref;
audioBansheeScreech.play();
```

I get an error saying

> `audioBansheeScreech.play()` is not a function

because `audioBansheeScreech` is a string. I can see round this with for loops and if statements, but I would much rather avoid.

Comment: try  `this.sound.add("audioBanshee" + ref, { volume: 0.5 }).play()`

Comment: Don't know about phaser, but you should probably create an array of `audioBanshee`. Then get a random using `array[ref]`

Comment: thanks Alex, tried that I get another error.. looks like I will have to go in that direction adiga... just thought there may be a trick in java script. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be easier to move these into an object, then you can call them by using a string:

```
const audioBanshees = {
  audioBanshee0: this.sound.add('audioBanshee0',{volume: 0.5}),
  audioBanshee1: this.sound.add('audioBanshee1',{volume: 0.5}),
  audioBanshee2: this.sound.add('audioBanshee2',{volume: 0.5}),
  audioBanshee3: this.sound.add('audioBanshee3',{volume: 0.5}),
  audioBanshee4: this.sound.add('audioBanshee4',{volume: 0.5})
}

let ref = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(5));

const audioBansheeScreech = audioBanshees["audioBanshee" + ref];

audioBansheeScreech.play()
```

---

Though IMO, an array here would be more logical and easier to read:

```
const audioBanshees = [
  this.sound.add('audioBanshee0',{volume: 0.5}),
  this.sound.add('audioBanshee1',{volume: 0.5}),
  this.sound.add('audioBanshee2',{volume: 0.5}),
  this.sound.add('audioBanshee3',{volume: 0.5}),
  this.sound.add('audioBanshee4',{volume: 0.5})
]

let ref = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(5));

const audioBansheeScreech = audioBanshees[ref];

audioBansheeScreech.play()
```

Comment: why do you say more logical?

Comment: Only because here we want to store and access a flat list of values, using a random index as the identifier. An array is more suited to this task, rather than an object (IMO), but both methods would work.